# Why is emf 0 for coil rotating in field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Say you have a coil (that can carry a current) rotating in the field between two magnets. When the area of the coil is perpendicular to the field lines the emf induced in the coil is 0, why is this?

Comment: Because the change of flux $\dot\Phi$ in the coil is zero at that moment in time. Look at the geometry and calculate the flux as a function of time, then differentiate with regards to time.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thanks. I know how to do it by calculating $\Phi=BAN\cos \omega t$ then differentiating to get $\varepsilon$ but I still can't see intuitively (without calculation) why the change in flux at that point is 0.

Comment: Intuitively one would probably basically repeat a quirky version of why the first derivative of the cosine is zero at its maximum... because the change in the product of normal vector and field doesn't change in first order. Is that any different than the math? Not really. Maybe somebody else has a better argument...